# Convert SOLR query to ElasticSearch URI format

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene

I've moved my SOLR core documents to ElasticSearch index. Now I need to convert my SOLR query parameters to ES format. I've seen the ES documentation here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html but ES doesn't have all the **URI** query parameters with name like **fq**, **group**, **boost**, **facet** etc.

From the documentation I came know below query parameters mapping between SOLR and ES. May be I am missing others, Please let me know those.

**SOLR to ES** :  fl -> _source, q -> q, rows -> size, start -> from, sort->sort

I know that I can use the query string of ES with the **source** parameters but I don't want to use that(because then I need to change a lot of my current system). See the answer of @Val here [Convert Elasticsearch kibana query string format to URI Search format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358344/convert-elasticsearch-kibana-query-string-format-to-uri-search-format?answertab=active#tab-top)

My final Goal is to convert the below **SOLR** query with **ES** but using URI search parameters not the query string. *These all parameters I can set on URI search for SOLR*

```
{
  "facet": "true",
  "sort": "",
  "facet.mincount": "1",
  "indent": "true",
  "facet.limit": "-1",
  "group.limit": "48",
  "wt": "json",
  "rows": "48",
  "fl": "id,code:feed_provider_id,feed_provider_id,feed,property_name,pax:occupancy,bedroom_count,min_stay,star_rating,night_rate_min,currency,picture:feature_image,latlon,image_count,display,parent_path,categories,rating,min_stay,archived,feed_provider_url,featured,direct,rating,ha_24_hour_response_s,base_usd_currency:currency(night_rate_min,'USD')",
  "facet.query": "{!key='Other'}(-property_type_categories:*)",
  "start": "0",
  "q": "(((latlon:[48.815573,2.225193 TO 48.9021449,2.4699208]) AND  (country:france OR country:FRANCE OR country_code:FR OR country_code:fr)) OR (parent_path:*,187147,* OR location_id:187147))",
  "group.field": "feed",
  "facet.field": [
    "amenity_category",
    "property_type_categories"
  ],
  "group": "true",
  "group.offset": "0",
  "fq": [
    "-latlon:0.001,0.001",
    "published:1",
    "night_rate_min:[0.01,USD TO 100000,USD]",
    "feed:11 OR feed:12 OR feed:13 OR feed:14",
    "night_rate_min:[75,EUR TO 250,EUR]",
    "-booked_date:[2018-02-23T00:00:00Z TO 2018-02-26T00:00:00Z] AND min_stay:[* TO 3]",
    "occupancy:[3 TO *]",
    "property_type_categories:('cabin' OR 'house')"
  ]
}
```

So, my basic question is

**Is this possible to fully convert my above SOLR query to ES format using URI search parameters?**

or

**I need to use both URI search and query string parameters?**

Please suggest me how can I covert my current queries on ES format?

Comment: have you found out something you want to share?

Comment: No not found very helpful resources regarding conversion between SOLR to ES query easily. That's why not able to share.