# Elasticsearch request query without post body (not allowed to add body)

Tags: elasticsearch, stackdriver

I need to do this

```
GET /my-index/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-1h"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From stackdriver uptime check. Problem is they don't allow post body. How can I do this?
[image]

Comment: If you can add a query string to the path, then this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48360002/4604579

Comment: yes exactly what I need